# Clicking a SegmentedControl to UITableViewCell in Monotouch causes SIGABRT

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, sigabrt

In my Monotouch application for the iPhone, I'm trying to add a segmented controller to a UITableViewCell to act as a toggle for a value in each row.  Everything displays correctly, and the first rows will initially work correctly when clicked. However, after the row has left the screen and is reloaded, if I clicked the segmented controller again I receive an exception:

Terminating runtime due to unhandled exception
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Exception: Selector invoked from objective-c on a managed object of type MonoTouch.UIKit.UIControlEventProxy (0x16D793C0) that has been GC'ed ---> System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for MonoTouch.UIKit.UIControlEventProxy::.ctor(System.IntPtr)

I have heard of similar issues with people using Monotouch try to put buttons in table cells.  The general recommendation has been to add each table cell to a List to prevent it from being garbage collected, but this has not worked for me.

Is there a solution to get around this problem?

Here is a somewhat simplified version of my GetCell code:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {

            Hashtable rowData = dataList [indexPath.Row];
            FilterListToggleCell cell;
            cell = (FilterListToggleCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("FilterTogglePlusCell");


            cacheList.Add(cell.Toggle);//cache only the segcontrol
                            //cacheList.Add(cell);//also previously tried caching the whole cell


            cell.Title.Text = (string)rowData["title"];
            if(additionalFields.Contains((string)rowData["key"])){
                cell.Toggle.SelectedSegment = 0;
            } else {
                cell.Toggle.SelectedSegment = 1;

            }



            cell.Toggle.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => {
                UISegmentedControl toggle = (UISegmentedControl)sender;

                if(toggle.SelectedSegment == 0){
                    Console.WriteLine("Toggle YES");
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine("Toggle NO");
                }

            };



            cell.Toggle.Tag = indexPath.Row;

            return cell;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the *basic* condition. This condition happens because there's no **managed** reference to the `UITableViewCell` that you return from the `GetCell` method.  As such the GC can collect and free it (and that will cause issues for things like events that wants to call back to the managed instance). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12353010/220643) for more details.

Now I'm not sure why this approach did not work for you. However your code above seems incomplete, e.g.

```
cell = (FilterListToggleCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("FilterTogglePlusCell");
```

can return `null` which is when you should be creating more cells (in fact there's no condition where you actually create any new cell, so there's nothing that can be re-used).

Your next line will throw a `NullReferenceException` when `cell` is null (because of `cell.Toggle`).

Note that this does not explain your crash - I suspect there's some missing code that make it works (create cells) and that might not cache them correctly.

Comment: The problem in the code above (even when caching the managed cells) is probably caused by "cell.Toggle.ValueChanged += (sender, e)". If the cell was already used, it will have two event handlers the 2nd time, three the third time and so on. The previous handler will however reference a maybe now no longer valid cell/UISegmentedControl and crash. I propose to make the event handler not anonymous but a real method and remove it before reassigning it by calling "cell.Toggle.ValueChanged -= MyHandler; cell.Toggle.ValueChanged += MyHandler;".

Comment: Good point wrt multiple event handlers. In general the events are only set when creating, not when re-using, the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working without needing the extra cache based on information from this question: [How do I remove/unregister event handler from an event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430467/how-do-i-remove-unregister-event-handler-from-an-event)

The ValueChanged line was replaced with:

```
cell.Toggle.AddTarget(this, new Selector("ToggleChange"),UIControlEvent.ValueChanged);
```

and another method was added to my UITableViewDataSource

```
[Export ("ToggleChange")]
void OnChange(UISementedControl toggle){
    if(toggle.SelectedSegment == 0){
        Console.WriteLine("Toggle YES");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Toggle NO");
    }
}
```